# How can I split the algorithm into two pages?

Tags: page-breaking, algorithms

How can I have the algorithm not break in the next page and rather split this into two pages?

```
\usepackage[ruled,german,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} % Pseudocode
\newcommand{\SkipBeforeAndAfter}{\vspace{0.32cm}} % verändert den Abstand zwischen Algorithmus

\begin{document}
Die HGS-CVRP besteht aus folgenden Schritten:

    \SetAlgoSkip{SkipBeforeAndAfter}
    \label{sec:HGS-CVRP}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{HGS-CVRP}
    \caption{Die HGS-CVRP}
    Initialisiere die Population aus zwei Subpopulationen bzw. eine feasible und infeasible Subpopulation) mit zufälligen Lösungen, die durch lokale Suche verbessert wurden;\\
    \While{die Anzahl der Iterationen ohne Verbesserung < $It_{NI}$ und die Zeit < $T_{MAX}$}{

        Wähle den Elternlösungen $P_1$ und $P_2$ aus;\\
        Wende den Crossover-Operator auf $P_1$ und $P_2$ an, um einen Nachkommen $C$ zu erzeugen;\\
        Bilde Nachkommen $C$ durch lokale Suche aus;\\
        Füge $C$ in die entsprechende Teilpopulation ein;\\
        \If{$C$ ist unzulässig}{
            Mit einer Wahrscheinlichkeit von 50\%, repariere $C$ (lokale Suche) und füge es in die entsprechende Teilpopulation ein;\\
        }
        \If{die maximale Teilpopulationsgröße ist erreicht}{
            Wähle Überlebende aus;\\
        }
        Passe Strafkoeffizienten für Unzulässigkeit an;\\
    } 
    \Return die beste zulässige Lösung;\\
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{algorithm}[H]` indicates that this is a float and these are a single unbreakable box.

Comment: Additionally please extend your example to a full minimal example others can copy and work with as is.

Comment: Breaking algorithms is usually not automatically done. Maybe you can extract a part of the algorithm into a sub method and typeset it in a second algorithm environment such that one of it fits on the page 4?